# Flash remoting and floating point values

Tags: actionscript-3

in xxxx.mxml (from flex) i have called the remote remote method (of java) the method return type is float
in the xxxx.mxml's remote objects result handler i need get the float values as Numeric.....or String..i tried with string...i did Alert.show to see the value some times i get exact value for eg, 0.5 is the value returning from java methid but here it will show 0.50000454...so on..how get the exact value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the way floating point numbers are stored; basically they can't be stored precisely. A quick search in SO would reveal a lot of [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907114/integers-and-float-precision/1907128#1907128) about this. Also read ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg%5Fgoldberg.html)

Thus the problem of getting the exact value boils down to what you define exact to be. Try rounding it to a given number of floating points at java end, convert the rounded number to a string (I'm not sure if this conversion would preserve the precision) and send that string.