# Having trouble with casting: (int)

Tags: c

I have 2 doubles x and y. When I divide x/y I dont get the result I am hoping to get.

Here is the printf command I am using in c and the output I am getting:

command:

```
printf("%3.10f %3.2f %3.12f %d\n",x,y,x/y,(int)(x/y));
```

output:

```
1.0000000000 0.10 10.000000000000 9
```

To me, x/y ought to be 10 and so not sure why (int)(x/y) is producing 9 instead of 10.

Can someone help me understand this surce of this problem please?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587442/casting-int-as-float

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722293/why-comparing-double-and-float-leads-to-unexpected-result/6722297#6722297) should be a good read.

Comment: @Polynominal: Not a dupe. That question is casting an int to float. This question here is casting the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you are truncating the decimal part. Round it, and you should be fine.

```
printf("%3.10f %3.2f %3.12f %d\n",x,y,x/y,round(x/y));
```

Answer (score 4):

`x/y` results in slightly less than 10 (it surely is less than 10^-12 off, otherwise the other result wouldn't show as 10.000000000000), probably due to the usual floating point math rounding errors.

The `printf` performs rounding to the digit of the requested precision, but the conversion to `int` is a brutal truncation, thus, even if it's 9.99999999999999... you get 9 as a result.

Comment: +1 for explaining why it doesn't show up in the double output.

Comment: I also did explain it. A lot shorter.

Comment: @RokKralj: he's referring to why the third field prints out as `10.000000000000` although it's a bit off - which you didn't explain.

Answer (score 1):

casting to int doesn't round a double to the nearest integer.

Look at [round() for float in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485525/round-for-float-in-c) for details