# Javascript floating point number addition

Tags: javascript, floating-point

PFB an example code snippet illustrating the issue:

```
        var x=0.323;
        var cumulativeVal = 0;

        for(i=0;i<30;i++){
                   cumulativeVal = cumulativeVal + x;
                   console.log(cumulativeVal);
        }
```

The result of the above computation is

```
  0.323
  0.646
  0.9690000000000001
  1.292
  1.615....
  4.845000000000001
  5.168000000000001
  5.491000000000001
  5.814000000000002....
  9.690000000000007
```

Note that an extra decimal value is getting added. I do understand that this has something to do with precision of values in javascript. But can anyone explain?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907114/integers-and-float-precision for an good answer on how floats are stored.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing particular to explain. [IEEE-754 double-precision numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#IEEE_754%3a_floating_point_in_modern_computers) are not completely, perfectly precise in decimal terms. Small errors can creep in. For full decimal precision (which, you should note, cannot perfectly represent one-third) you'd need to use a type designed for that. (JavaScript doesn't have one built in; examples from other languages would be `BigDecimal` from Java, or `decimal` from C#.)

There's an easier example, by the way:

```
0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004
```

It's one of [Crockford's](http://javascript.crockford.com) favorites.

Comment: Thanks . As for the easy example, never realized this all these years :)